# Set vimeo thumbnail from video with Apps Script - it keeps returning the stripes image

Tags: javascript, video, thumbnails, vimeo

Unlike most queries here I'm trying to ***set*** the thumbnail of a video using the API.
For this I'm not uploading an image, I'm trying to get an image 15 seconds into the video and setting it active as the thumbnail.

When I do this via the API documentation test section it works perfectly fine, but the below code only generates the error stripes image and wont set it to active.
Any thoughts?

[Here](https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/thumbnails#creating-a-thumbnail) is what the documentation suggests, and note that I have the 'upload' privileges for my app.

I believe it has something to do with the 'payload' line, and the "{15}".

```
vimeotoken = "###############....etc";

function setthumbnail(){

      var url = 'https://api.vimeo.com/videos/' + '##########' + '/pictures';

      var options = { 
        'method': 'POST',
        'muteHttpExceptions': true,
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'headers': {
          'Accept':'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
          'Authorization': "Bearer " + vimeotoken,
        },
        'payload': JSON.stringify([{ "time": "{15}", "active": true }]),
      };
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);  
      Logger.log(response);
      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out all I needed was to remove the array for the payload line.
From:

```
'payload': JSON.stringify([{ "time": "{15}", "active": true }]),
```

To:

```
'payload': JSON.stringify({ "time": "{15}", "active": true }),
```